# How to insert date with awk in linux in the header record,

Tags: linux, awk

I am trying to insert current date and end of the current month date in the header record of the file as follows:

```
"ABCDEF            MC             20201006      FB   XXX1           20201006 20201031"
```

I tried the following with just trying to change one date - two dates at the end I hardcoded for now:

```
awk 'BEGIN{print "ABCDEF            MC             ""d=$(date)""      FB   XXX1           ""20201005"" ""20201031"}1' tmp.txt >> tmpH.txt
```

Desired output should look like this:

"ABCDEF            MC             20201006      FB   XXX1           20201006 20201031"

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way of doing it is using bash to compute the dates, and retrieve the values as variables from within awk:

```
echo "test" | awk -v today="$(date +%Y%m%d)" -v last_day="$(date +"%Y%m%d" -d "$(date +%Y-%m-01) +1 month -1 day")" 'BEGIN { print "ABCDEF MC " today " FB XXX1 " today, last_day }'
```

[Source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/224969/current-date-in-awk)

Result:

```
ABCDEF MC 20201006 FB XXX1 20201006 20201031
```

To get the last day of the current month we format the current date to %Y-%m-01 = 2020-10-01, then add 1 month, and subtract 1 day.